# How to write a function that returns text or integer values?

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

postgres=# select version();

```
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

[sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/67bf6/3)

My Query executes the insertion safely. What i need is that my function should return something except the void datatype. Something like text("inserted into table") or integer(0-false,1-true) , it will be useful for me to validate whether it is inserted or not?

I need a syntax for a function that returns an `integer` or a `text` when an insertion is done. For validation purpose. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: `returns integer` instead of `returns void`?

Comment: Have you tried `RETURNING` clause for `INSERT` query? Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Which parts of the Postgres' documentation about functions on PL/pgSQL are not clear or helpful?

Comment: What client driver are you using? Java + PgJDBC? C# + nPgSQL? Python + psycopg2? What? **You need to do this on the client side**.

Comment: java + pgJDBC is my driver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What you probably need

Most likely you need one function to return `text` and another one to return `integer` or a function that returns `boolean` to indicate success. All of this is trivial and I'll refer you to the [excellent manual on `CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) or [code examples in similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%22RETURNS%20boolean%22).

#### What you actually asked

> How to write a function that returns text or integer values?

... in the sense that we have *one* return type being either `text` or `integer`. Not as trivial, but also not impossible as has been suggested. The key word is: [**polymorphic types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).

Building on this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  tbl_id int,
  txt    text,
  nr     int
);
```

This function returns either integer or text (or any other type if you allow it), depending on the input type.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_insert_data(_id int, _data anyelement, OUT _result anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN

CASE pg_typeof(_data) 
WHEN 'text'::regtype THEN
    INSERT INTO tbl(tbl_id, txt) VALUES(_id, _data)
    RETURNING txt
    INTO _result;

WHEN 'integer'::regtype THEN
    INSERT INTO tbl(tbl_id, nr) VALUES(_id, _data)
    RETURNING nr
    INTO _result;

ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected data type: %', pg_typeof(_data)::text;
END CASE;

END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_insert_data(1, 'foo'::text);  -- explicit cast needed.
SELECT f_insert_data(1, 7);
```

#### Simple case

*One* function that returns `TRUE` / `FALSE` to indicate whether a row has been inserted, only one input parameter of varying type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_insert_data2(_id int, _data anyelement)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
BEGIN

CASE pg_typeof(_data)
WHEN 'text'::regtype THEN
   INSERT INTO tbl(tbl_id, txt) VALUES(_id, _data);

WHEN 'integer'::regtype THEN
   INSERT INTO tbl(tbl_id, nr) VALUES(_id, _data);

ELSE
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected data type: >>%<<', pg_typeof(_data)::text;
END CASE;

IF FOUND THEN RETURN TRUE;
ELSE RETURN FALSE;
END IF;

END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The input type can be replaced with a `text` parameter for most purposes, which can be cast to and from any other type.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the whole idea behind this *really weird*? Just using the affected-row-count when doing the insert standalone should be fine, and otherwise there's `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, `FOUND` and `INSERT ... RETURNING`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Must be just you. :p Seriously, I don't think the OP needs any of this, as already hinted every so gently. It's advanced stuff for special purposes.

Comment: Yeah. I've added an example of how to do it the sane way, using Python since the tools/language used by the OP aren't specified. I suspect they're in a place that's drunk the "stored procedures for everything" kool-aid without actually *understanding* it, though...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're solving a problem by creating a bigger problem.

You don't need a function for this at all. Do it on the client side by checking the affected rows count that's returned by every DML query, or use `INSERT ... RETURNING`.

You didn't mention your client language, so here's how to do it in Python with `psycopg2`. The same approach applies in other languages with syntax variations.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psycopg2

# Connect to the db
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Set up the table to use
curs.execute("""
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS so17587735;

CREATE TABLE so17587735 (
    id serial primary key,
    blah text not null
);
""");

# Approach 1: Do the insert and check the rowcount:
curs.execute("""
INSERT INTO so17587735(blah) VALUES ('whatever');
""");
if curs.rowcount != 1:
    raise Exception("Argh, insert affected zero rows, wtf?")
print("Inserted {0} rows as expected".format(curs.rowcount))

# Approach 2: Use RETURNING
curs.execute("""
INSERT INTO so17587735(blah) VALUES ('bored') RETURNING id;
""");
returned_rows = curs.fetchall();
if len(returned_rows) != 1:
    raise Exception("Got unexpected row count {0} from INSERT".format(len(returned_rows)))

print("Inserted row id is {0}".format(returned_rows[0][0]))
```

In the case of PL/PgSQL calling `INSERT` you can use [the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS), the `FOUND` variable, or `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE INSERT ... RETURNING ...`. Using `GET DIAGNOSTICS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blah() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    inserted_rows integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('whatever');
    GET DIAGNOSTICS inserted_rows = ROW_COUNT;
    IF inserted_rows <> 1 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Failed to insert rows; expected 1 row, got %', inserted_rows;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

or if you must return values and must for some reason use PL/PgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blah() RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('whatever') RETURNING id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

(assuming the key is `id`)

which would be the same as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blah() RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('whatever') RETURNING id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

or just

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ('whatever') RETURNING id;
```

In other words: Why wrap this in a function? It doesn't make sense. Just check the row-count client side, either with `RETURNING` or by using the client driver's affected-rows count for `INSERT`.

Comment: actually the scenario is that i have a back-end code using functions as i kept the SQL FIDDLE of it! when i am connecting it with java frontend i need a response from the function i.e.., a return value so that i can make sure that insertion into database is been done..so i want to clarify whether is there any chance of returning a value to the function which is been called. or is there any other way to solve this? @craig rainger

Comment: @user2561626 Sure. Check `GET DIAGNOSTICS` in the procedure, and `RAISE EXCEPTION` if it reports no rows.

Comment: @user2561626 Answer rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

A function can only return one type.  In your case, you could create a composite type with two fields, one integer and one text, and return that.

Comment: OK, partially.  Polymorphic return types require a polymorphic argument, which isn't the case here.