# Multiply elements in an array according to their position

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, set-returning-functions

What is an efficient function I could use to increase the amount of elements in an array by their position?

For example, if I have an array of:

```
ARRAY[10,20,30,40,50]::INT[]
```

I would like that to turn into:

```
ARRAY[10,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,50,50,50,50,50]::INT[]
```

So that I have 1 "10", 2 "20", 3 "30", 4 "40", and 5 "50".

For the array:

```
ARRAY[10,20,30,40,10]::INT[]
```

I would like that to turn into:

```
ARRAY[10,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40,40,10,10,10,10,10]::INT[]
```

So that I have 6 "10", 2 "20", 3 "30" and 4 "40".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT ARRAY[10,20,30,40,50]::INT[] AS arr)   -- variable for demo
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT unnest(array_fill(arr[idx], ARRAY[idx])) AS mult
   FROM  (SELECT arr, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS idx FROM t) sub
   );
```

I would wrap the logic into a simple IMMUTABLE SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_expand_arr(_arr anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT unnest(array_fill(_arr[idx], ARRAY[idx]))
   FROM  (SELECT generate_subscripts(_arr, 1) AS idx) sub
   )
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Works for arrays of *any* base type due to the polymorphic parameter type `anyarray`:
[How to write a function that returns text or integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587735/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-text-or-integer-values/17605114#17605114)

The manual on [`generate_subscripts()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) and [`array_fill()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

Note: This works with the actual *array indexes*, which can differ from the ordinal array position in Postgres. You may be interested in @Daniel's method to "normalize" the array index:
[Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1/12012285#12012285)

The upcoming Postgres 9.4 (currently beta) provides `WITH ORDINALITY`:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Allowing for this even more elegant and reliable solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_expand_arr(_arr anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT unnest(array_fill(a, ARRAY[idx]))
   FROM   unnest(_arr) WITH ORDINALITY AS x (a, idx)
   )
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

One might still argue that proper order is not actually *guaranteed*. I claim it is ...
[Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)

Call:

```
SELECT f_expand_arr(ARRAY[10,20,30,40,10]::INT[]) AS a2;
```

Or for values from a table:

```
SELECT f_expand_arr(a) AS a2 FROM t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8480/1)